# Pathological curvature

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, extreme-value, adam

How common is the issue of pathological curvature? I have been reading a post on the internet about it, and I would like to know how common this happens with deep learning models.

Could you also inform ways to diagnosis whether it is happening or not?

in case you don't know what is pathological curvature, here it is the explanation of it.
https://blog.paperspace.com/intro-to-optimization-momentum-rmsprop-adam/